# Is receive(:method).never completely equivalent to not_to receive(:method)

Tags: ruby, rspec

Using RSpec 3.7.0. I would like to know whether writing

```
expect(instance).not_to receive(:method)
```

is **completely** identical to writing

```
expect(instance).to receive(:method).never
```

or if there are any (even subtle) differences or side effects.

Comment: [`receive.rb#33`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/5cba05bbe37d446c4bf66343b2166d9c18e295ab/lib/rspec/mocks/matchers/receive.rb#L33) – seems like `not_to receive` uses `never` under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this link https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/895 
You can use either of these to cause an example to fail if a method is called
Author @myronmarston also provided an example